# Flash drive unmounted by itself

Tags: usb, mount, flash

Yesterday I mounted my flash drive properly to a folder in my home directory. However, I had to restart my computer to finish installing updates, and when I logged back on, my flash drive was unmounted. It was back in the DEVICES tab in Files and I had to remount it the exact same way I did yesterday. This is how I originally mounted my flash drive:

```
sudo umount /media/my_name/MY_NAME 
sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/sdx1 /home/my_name/folder_name
sudo mount -o remount,exec /home/my_name/folder_name
```

These same commands have worked well for me in the past on other computers. That is why I am confused as to why I had to remount my flash drive.

*Edit* : I just restarted my computer again and the same thing happened. So now I see that my flash drive is unmounting every time my computer restarts.

Thank you.

Comment: This is by design. If you want to have your drive mounted permanently, you have to add an entry in `/etc/fstab`. Alternative, as the drive is automatically mounted on `/media/my_name/MY_NAME`, and you want have access through `/home/my_name/folder_name`, you may create a link there like `ln -s /media/my_name/MY_NAME /home/my_name/folder_name` (the folder `folder_name`must not exist in this case).

Comment: @ridgy I have read about `/etc/fstab` a lot but I don't know what it is. Would you mind helping me permanently mount my flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

Without the content of "/etc/fstab" it is difficult to say what your mount commands did (permanently). If you can compare it with another similarly configured system you should be able to spot the difference.

Comment: The issue occurs each time I restart my computer

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/fstab` in general holds information for mounting devices to mount points for use by the `mount` command without having to pass information like filesystem, options and the like. A special purpose is to keep information for automatically mount (via `mount -a`), which is e.g. issued at boot.

The format and content of the file is thoroughly declared in `man fstab`. Following is a short description for your special question, which only applies to local devices (for NFS, CIFS, loop devices etc. it is a bit different).

`/etc/fstab` is a text file to be edited by any text editor. Lines beginning with `#` are comments, empty lines are ignored and the other lines contain six entries, separated by spaces or tabs:

`<device> <mountpoint> <fstype> <options> <dumpfreq> <fsckpass>`

where the last two entries usually are set to 0 for external devices. The entries are:

- device: The block special file (or a link to it) of the filesystem to mount
- mountpoint: Where to mount the device
- fstype: Type of the filesystem
- options: The mount options as given to the `mount` command.

In your example, you would write

```
/dev/sdx1 /home/my_name/folder_name vfat rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,exec 0 0
```

but you should not do this way.

First, you cannot be sure to have always the same device name (/dev/sdb1 e.g.), as when adding a second flash disk this could change. So it is better to use the UUID or the LABEL of the partition (if it is labelled). To find out issue `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` and `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label` and look for entries that point to the respective partition: e.g.:

```
ridgy@desk:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  1 12:16 0de814aa-0263-423a-a9f3-f2919db02700 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  1 12:16 9325-22B3 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  1 12:16 acf415b5-cdbf-4c18-9226-2a9be8d65d78 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  1 12:16 cd14a697-5bec-4a6c-8c55-2afb3a410ee6 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  1 12:16 E596-07F2 -> ../../sda1
```

which says that e.g. /dev/sdb1 has a UUID of 9325-22B3 etc., and

```
ridgy@desk:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  1 14:02 data -> ../../sdc1
```

says that /dev/sdc1 has a filesystem labelled `data`.

So you should enter `UUID=<uuid>` or `LABEL=<label>` instead of the device node.

Next, when mounting this way during boot, all mounts are done by root. Especially with FAT filesystems this means to have `root` as owner and group of all the directories and files, what usually is not intended. So you should also pass UID and GID as options to the mount: `uid=<my_uid>,gid=<my_gid>`.

Last, as this is an external USB drive, the boot process will stop for a long time, waiting for the device to come ready, if it is not there (unplugged). To avoid this add the option `nofail`, so `mount` will not fail when the device is not available.

To come to an end, you could **very carefully** proceed as follows:

**Make a backup of your current `/etc/fstab`**: `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bck`. **If in any way you corrupt your `/etc/fstab`, you may leave your system unbootable!** You then could boot from a Live USB/DVD and get your original fstab back.

With your favourite editor, edit the file `/etc/fstab` with sudo rights (e.g., `sudo nano /etc/fstab`). Make sure you know how to use the editor!

At the end, add the line

```
UUID=<my_uuid> /home/my_name/folder_name vfat rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=<my_uid>,gid=<my_gid>,exec,nofail 0 0
```

where you have to replace uuid, uid and gid according to your values. As noted above, instead of `UUID=<my_uuid>` you could also use `LABEL=<my_label>` if the filesystem is labelled.

Now, as the option `auto` is given, the filesystem will be mounted on boot if the device is available. If not, you may connect it later and issue `mount /home/my_name/folder_name`, as the option `user` allows any user to mount, and the entry in `/etc/fstab` corresponding to your mountpoint holds all necessary information.